# Mono For Android In app Billing

Tags: android, for-loop, mono, in-app-billing

Does anyone have a working example of setting up in app billing in mandroid I am using JNI to access java classes but I seem to have gotten stuck with declaring a transaction handler in one of my actvities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a repository on Github](https://github.com/MarkEaton1/Monodroid-InApp-Billing) that claims to have what you need it was published along with [theese comments on the mono mailing list](http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Code-for-people-to-download-for-in-app-billing-td5711735.html):

> this has been tested with real money for managed in-app products only. All the code is there for unmanaged products and subscriptions, it just needs to be tested.

Good luck :-)